# Jython, websphere : Operation getStatsObject not in ModelMBeanInfo

Tags: websphere, jython

Could you please help me to get the current value of ActiveCount (ThreadPoolModule) in websphere ?

Below you can  find my code and the error generated :

```
perfName = AdminControl.completeObjectName ('name=WebContainer,type=ThreadPool,process=G5-WLS,*')
perfOName = AdminControl.makeObjectName (perfName)
sigs = ['javax.management.ObjectName', 'java.lang.Boolean']
jvmName = AdminControl.completeObjectName ('name=WebContainer,type=ThreadPool,process=G5-WLS,*')
params = [AdminControl.makeObjectName (jvmName), java.lang.Boolean ('false')] 
jvmStats=AdminControl.invoke_jmx (perfOName, 'getStatsObject', params, sigs)
ActiveCount=jvmStats.getStatistic( 'ActiveCount').getCurrent()
```

Error in line 6 :

```
wsadmin> jvmStats=AdminControl.invoke_jmx (perfOName, 'getStatsObject', params, sigs)
WASX7015E: Exception reÃ§ue lors de l'exÃ©cution de la commande : " jvmStats=AdminControl.invoke_jmx (perfOName, 'getStatsObject', params, sigs)"; informations sur l'exception :
javax.management.MBeanException
javax.management.ServiceNotFoundException: Operation getStatsObject not in ModelMBeanInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have found the answer :

```
perfName = AdminControl.completeObjectName ('type=Perf,process=G5-WLS,*')
perfOName = AdminControl.makeObjectName (perfName)
sigs = ['javax.management.ObjectName', 'java.lang.Boolean']
threadPoolName = AdminControl.completeObjectName ('name=WebContainer,type=ThreadPool,process=G5-WLS,*')
params = [AdminControl.makeObjectName (threadPoolName), java.lang.Boolean ('false')]
jvmStats=AdminControl.invoke_jmx (perfOName, 'getStatsObject', params, sigs)
ActiveCount=jvmStats.getStatistic( 'ActiveCount').getCurrent()
```

And the result :

```
wsadmin>print ActiveCount
1
```